# In php, when working with very small numbers, how can i see the exact number, and not "2.1934509277344E-5"?

Tags: unix, math

I am working with microtime() to time some scripts, but all the scripts have really quick times, eg 2.1934509277344E-5

how can i get php to display that correctly without e-5?

(which i assume is 0.000021934509277344? long time since i did maths...)

Comment: PHP is doing its best to show you the exact number. Do you want more decimal places? What would be the preferred output format? 21.9 microseconds would be most readable.

Comment: Hi,

re: those that said about printf - thanks :) just what i was after

re: microseconds - makes no difference if its microseconds or whatever. was just hard to quickly see the differnce when it was all e-6 etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(s)printf`

```
$myVal = 0.0000002;
echo $myVal;   // "2.0E-7"
printf("%0.7f", $myVal);  // "0.0000002"
```

Comment: For further clarification, you can mess around with the number of decimal places it shows by changing the first parameter of the printf function. "%0.7f" = floating point # with 7 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `trim(sprintf('%40.20f', 2.1934509277344E-5))`. `%40.20f` tells sprintf to display 40 digit with 20 digit of decimal. You can adjust this as you wish. The number will be space-led to fill 40 digits so I trim it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you could just use `%0.20f`, which won't pad to the left at all.