# How do I convert 2.0E-6 to 0.00000200?

Tags: php

How do I convert 2.0E-6 to 0.00000200?

I try to multiply 0.00000100 by 2 and I need the exact value.

Comment: Do you mean you want to format a float as a string, and never write it using scientific notation? In that case, have you tried `sprintf("%.08F", value)`? Consult the [manual of `sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to see how the format string works. Also, keep in mind that floating point numbers (by design!) will never be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [number_format()](http://us.php.net/function.number_format) to do what you want:

```
print number_format($your_var, 9);
```

That will give you the output in full decimal rather than notative.

Answer (score 0):

[similar question has already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665282/in-php-when-working-with-very-small-numbers-how-can-i-see-the-exact-number-an).

```
$myVal = 0.0000002;
echo $myVal;   // "2.0E-7"
printf("%0.7f", $myVal);  // "0.0000002"
```